# Resize gridview cell width with gridSplitter

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to work with grid Splitter.

[image]

Here i have 2 column which can be resized. other column headers are disabled.

1. How I can resize the column width of GridViewColumn when grid Splitter is used?

[image]

Comment: not sure if we understand what are you asking for? try explaining again with some code

Comment: HI @Muds i was trying to use gridsplitter and  datagrid.i was trying to acheive something like when the gridsplitter is moved, instead of hiding column of datagrid, each resizable columns should be resized equally.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i was trying to achieve something like when the gridsplitter is moved, instead of hiding column of datagrid, each resizable columns should be resized equally.

To solve this, instead of giving a width to resizable column as auto or fixed value, give it ***** like

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Owner Name"
                             Width="*"
                             MinWidth="100"
                             MaxWidth="250"
                             CanUserResize="True"
                             Binding="{Binding OwnerName}" />
```

and gridsplitter as

```
<GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitterStatusBar"
              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
              ResizeDirection="Columns"
              Background="Gray"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"       
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Cursor="ScrollWE"
              Width="2"/>
```

so whenever you will try to resize the datagrid, resizable columns will take the available space.